# Setup Yeoman with express server

Tags: node.js, yeoman

I am currently setting up my node project and have used Yeoman for scaffolding.

Now my next step is to setup the express server so i can setup my api's etc?

Should I just setup a Server folder where I can setup all expressJS elements and database calls?

How should I be running my server to run server-side code?

Hope someone can assist.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

First of all, input 'yo' on your terminal.you will see a menu,Select install a generator,if you want to create a express project,you can search express project, you can find generator-expressjs generator-express-angular and so on,you can start on this folders.here is an example.

step1: use Yeoman to create a express project

```
sudo npm install -g generator-expressjs
```

step2: install package

```
npm install
```

step3: run test server

```
grunt server
```

Comment: so instead of using node server.js command do I just use grunt? even on production

Comment: sure, you can just use grunt,but you should install npm to install grunt,you can use yo to find something generator what you want,such as angularjs,php,java and so on.

Comment: I'm getting more confused now. Do i need to add Expressjs for the server side so that i can create the api's?